# Как при парсинге пропускать случайные, ненужные числа?

Tags: c#, синтаксический-анализ

Имеется строка:

> "param1":631},"param2":"168435413138849"},"param3"

Как при парсинге необращать внимание на значение "param1"?

Если это важно, использую библиотеку xNet, метод .Substrings("начало","конец").

Answer (score 1):

Для разбора JSON пользуйтесь готовыми библиотеками, например, JSON.NET. Ручной разбор ни к чему хорошему не приведёт.